# Testing a static function by mocking a non-static function it calls in C

Tags: c

I have

program.h:

```
static int doSomething(int input);
```

program.c:

```
#include "program.h"

void sendSomethingToSomewhere(int things);

static int doSomething(int input)
{
  // other code
  sendSomethingToSomewhere(things);
  return x;
}

void sendSomethingToSomewhere(int things)
{
 // bad stuff
}
```

I want to test the doSomething function by creating a file test.c. program.h and program.c MUST NOT be modified. I want to replace the implementation of sendSomethingToSomewhere in program.c for my own in test.c, so that whenever doSomething calls sendSomethingToSomewhere, "good stuff" executes instead of "bad stuff". How do I do this?

test.c:

```
#include "program.h"

void test1();
void sendSomethingToSomewhere(int things);

void test1()
{
   int output = doSomething(4);
   printf("%d", output);
}

void sendSomethingToSomewhere(int things)
{
 // good stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for isn't possible.

The function you want to test lives in the same file as the function it calls that you don't want called.  If program.c can't be modified, there's no way to call `doSomething` without it calling `sendSomethingToSomewhere`.

If you want to be able to test `doSomething` in isolation you'll have to move it to a different source file from the one containing `sendSomethingToSomewhere`.